# Wordpress responsive theme header menu display: none issue

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm making a Wordpress site and I have a bit of problem with the menus.
I want the menu to switch places. The site is [www.procitajto.com](https://www.procitajto.com)

On the desktop webpage I want the menu to be below the logo, but on the mobile page I want to move it to the header.

I managed to hide the lower one on mobile using `display: none` in `responsive.css` but whatever I try to do to hide the upper one is moot. It is generated using php:

```
<?php do_action('et_header_menu'); ?>
        <?php $menuClass = 'nav';
        $menuID = 'top-menu';
        $primaryNav = '';
        if (function_exists('wp_nav_menu')) {
            $primaryNav = wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu', 'container' => '', 'fallback_cb' => '', 'menu_class' => $menuClass, 'menu_id' => $menuID, 'echo' => false ) );
        };
        if ($primaryNav == '') { ?>
            <ul id="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuID ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $menuClass ); ?>">
                <?php if (get_option('aggregate_home_link') == 'on') { ?>
                    <li <?php if (is_home()) echo('class="current_page_item"') ?>><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e('Home','Aggregate') ?></a></li>
                <?php }; ?>

                <?php show_page_menu($menuClass,false,false); ?>
                <?php show_categories_menu($menuClass,false); ?>
            </ul> <!-- end ul#nav -->
        <?php }
        else echo($primaryNav); ?>
```

In the css file I tried to force it to disappear by using

```
ul#top-menu { float: left; padding-left: 36px; display: none !important; }
```

as a last resort but even that didn't work.

Comment: Seems to work fine, adding 'display:none;' in browser.

Comment: I got it to work in a roundabout way: I added a new class `disappearing` that has a `display: none` style, then I just overwrote that style in `responsive.css` by using `.disappearing { display: inline !important; }`